# Where does Windows download its Windows Spotlight content from?

Tags: windows-spotlight

Where are Windows Spotlight's lock screen backgrounds and helpful tips downloaded from?

Is there a way to ask this link for just its images? And do the images come from a different link than the tips, so that the tips link could be blocked?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia [Windows spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_spotlight) :

> Windows spotlight is a feature included with Windows 10 and Windows 11 which downloads images and advertisements **from Bing** and displays them as background wallpapers on the lock screen. In 2017, Microsoft began adding location information for many of the photographs.

The Wikipedia article contains more details about the search in Bing.